# Java Class Loader issue/Maven issue in multiple Jetty container

Tags: java, spring, maven, jetty, containers

I have a big appliance running using multiple application. I have multiple Jetty containers where multiple applications are deployed to each container.. Now, i am facing a simple class not found warning while deploying the application.

This is my analysis:

1. JettyContainer_1 contain App_1 which has many common JAR files which can be shared across all other containers so all applications can access these JAR files.
2. Now, the problems is that a spring framework class in shared libs in JettyContainer_1 is trying to load a class "ClassAInContainer3"(from jar file) from App_X in container 3. Then am getting the class not found error..

Here is the stack trace..

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.ClassAInContainer3
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258) ~[spring-core.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultJavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJavaTypeMapper.java:82) ~[spring-amqp.jar:na]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
2015-08-19 05:38:16.123 UTC,WARN ,App1-web,messaging,com.test.Rabbit,null,SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1,Caught an exception while handling a rabbitmq message, Publisher/Consumer should have handled this.
org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [com.test.ClassAInContainer3]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultJavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJavaTypeMapper.java:85) ~[spring-amqp.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultJavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJavaTypeMapper.java:53) ~[spring-amqp.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter.fromMessage(JsonMessageConverter.java:117) ~[spring-amqp.jar:na]
```

Any inputs on how to resolve this.. I am using Maven for building the application.. I suspect this is becoz since both libs are in different location, the spring class(present in jettyContainer1) cannot load the ClassAInContainer3 from App_3. So may be we can add some dependencies or class loader configurations..

Any inputs will be much appreciated.. Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: shared lib do not seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The exception makes sense if the "spring framework class" is loaded by the Jetty class loader and the `ClassAInContainer3` is loaded by the `WebAppClassLoader` (typically so, if it is in WEB-INF/lib or WEB-INF/classes of a webapp).

I started a Jetty server in debug and executed the following commands (in the Display view in Eclipse) while blocked in a breack point inside a web controller (i.e. I'm executing code loaded by a `WebAppClassLoader`):

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader()
    org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader) WebAppClassLoader=653648989@26f5e45d
```

If I try to climb the class loader hierarchy, I get the server class loader of Jetty:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getParent()
    (org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm) ClassRealm[plugin>org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.2.v20150730, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@58644d46]
```

this is the root class loader, beyond this point I cannot go, in fact:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getParent().getParent()
    null
```

Now, if I invoke `loadClass` in the code of a class that's been loaded by the `AppClassLoader` (at server startup, typically), It will use its own class loader first (that is, the `AppClassLoader` itself) and then, if the class is not found, the parent class loader (because the servlet container will use a "parent last" loading strategy, but note that, as I stated before, there is no other class loader beyond `AppClassLoader`).

But it is perfectly feasible that the `ClassAInContainer3` is not reachable by the AppClassLoader, because it is not in the classpath that is known to it. In fact look what happens if I try to load an instance of my web controller (a class contained in WEB-INF/classes) with the `AppClassLoader`:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getParent().loadClass("org.test.showcase.HomeController")
    Evaluation failed. Reason(s):
        An exception occurred: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

Exactly what I suspect is happening in your case.

Comment: So is there any anyway by which I can load a class from one web container to another web container...

Comment: The point is not that you have 2 containers, nor the location of the shared libraries (at least this is my understanding). The point is the order in which the classes are loaded. If you manage to pass the right class loader around, then you can use it to load the class of your interest. whether this is possible in your system, this is for you to understand, I guess.

Comment: @abyin007 did you discover anything, then?